# If $G$ is a finite group and all non-identity elements of $G$ are order 2 then the product of these elements is the identity.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a finite group with $\vert G\vert>2$ and all non-identity elements of $G$ are order $2$, then the product of all the elements of $G$ is the identity.

Since all non identity elements are order 2 I already know that $G$ is abelian as $ab=(ba)^{-1}=ba$.

I was told there is a solution involving cosets, so here is what I have.

I know that there must be a 4 element subgroup of G. Since for 2 elements a,b. I can form a subgroup $H=\{e,a,b,ab\}$. Now this subgroup has the property if I take the product of the non identity elements, $a(b)(ab)=e$ since $H$ is abelian. Taking cosets of $H$ I get $xH=Hx$ since $G$ is abelian. I know the order of $G$ must be even since it's divisible by 2. And for any coset I have $xH=\{x,xa,xb,xab\}$

I also know that if my product is $a_1\cdot a_2\cdot ...\cdot a_n$ that each member of this product can only appear in each coset once as cosets are disjoint.

From here though I have no idea, I'm not even sure what this coset idea is even supposed to give me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, the group is abelian. Since it has no element of order $p$ for any odd prime $p$, the order of the group is divisible only by the prime $2$, so the order is a power of $2$.

The group then has a subgroup $H$ of index $2$, with a coset $aH$. To each element $h$ of $H$ there corresponds an element $ah$ of $aH$. The product of these two elements is $ah^2$, which is $a$. So the product of all the elements is $a^r$, where $r$, half the order of the group, is even, and we're done.

Comment: How can you get that subgroup $H$ without Sylow theory (out of curiosity)?

Comment: "So the product of all the elements is $a^r$, where $r$, half the order of the group, is even, and we're done" why does this imply that the product of all the non identity elements is the identity?

Comment: Because $a^r$ *is* the result of multiplying all the group elements and $a^r=a^{2k}=(a^2)^k$.

Comment: @Randall, we're dealing with abelian groiups here, so we don't need Sylow; the structure theorem for finite abelian groups will do. Alternatively, even for nonabelian groups, you can prove without Sylow that a group of order $p^r$ has a subgroup of order $p^{r-1}$, $p$ being prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  hmmm I don't know how to get your last fact without Sylow....

Comment: @Randall, or, you can do it like this: let $a\ne1$, then $a$ generates a subgroup of order 2; let $b$ not be in that subgroup, then $a,b$ generate a subgroup of order 4; let $c$ not be in *that* subgroup, then $a,b,c$ generate a subgroup of order 8; and so on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  ahh, interesting.

Comment: @Randall, you may be right about order $p^{r-1}$ and Sylow, I may have been thinking about the proof there's a nontrivial center, which is much less than what's needed. But the other approaches work.

Comment: Of course, if you've got the structure theorem for abelian groups, you know that $G=(\Bbb Z / 2 \Bbb Z)^n$ for some $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @Robert, true, but you still have to do a little work to get from there to the conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

Write  $G=\displaystyle\bigcup_{g\in G }gH $.

For $g_1,g_2\in G $, either $g_1H=g_2H $ or $g_1H\cap g_2H=\emptyset$. Let $G'$ be a set of all $g$'s with pairwise disjoint cosets. Then we can write  $G=\displaystyle\bigcup_{g\in G' }gH.$

Now the product of all elements can be written as $$\prod_{g\in G'}g\cdot ga\cdot gb\cdot gab =\prod_{g\in G'}g^4\cdot (ab)^2=1(\text{since $G$ is Abelian and every element is of order $2$}). $$

Comment: Can't you make the same argument using $H=\{e,a\}$?  To me, this seems more natural (and less work) than using a 4-element subgroup.  Is there somewhere the argument breaks down on a 2-element subgroup?

Comment: @Randall Yes, you're right. I don't see any problem. I was trying to extend the OP's approach.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that approach for the answer.  Just curious.  Been thinking about this a lot for some reason.

Comment: Either way, this is slick.

Comment: But this product isn't the product of the elements of $G$ because different elements of $G$ result in the same coset.  It's the product raised to the power of $[G:H]$, which doesn't help us because we already know that any element to an even power is $e$.

Comment: I took the union to be disjoint, which alleviates the problem, no?

Comment: That works, but then writing the product as spanning all $g \in G$ is at best misleading.  Should probably explain that this is a disjoint union and change the index of the product.

Comment: Agreed. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for the correction. I've edited my answer. Is it fine now?

Comment: To pick a nit, I'd call $G'$ *a* set of coset representatives, not *the* set.  But substantively it's fine.